# Oracle 18c how import .dmp file with impdp

Tags: oracle, import, oracle12c, oracle18c

I have a *.dmp file from a 3rd party partner who provides the data to work with. I want to import this into my local Oracle 18c database for a first round testing, as I'm quite new with Oracle databases.

They've also provided two long 'create table....' commands in a text file, so I reckon this dump file has data from 2 tables.

EDIT:
Using `impdp` following Alex Poole's suggestion, I'm getting the following errors:

```
C:\Users\myusername>impdp dumpfile=testdumpfile.dmp

Import: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Mar 26 18:18:18 2019
Version 18.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Username: c##myusername
Password:

Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production

Warning: Oracle Data Pump operations are not typically needed when connected to the root or seed of a container database.


UDI-31626: operation generated ORACLE error 31626
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 4750
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT_INT", line 2082
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT_INT", line 2062
ORA-39086: cannot retrieve job information
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT_INT", line 2055
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 2266
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 4499
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 6104
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: Are you sure the file was created with legacy `exp`, rather than the more sensible data pump `expdp`? The separate table creation commands are a bit odd though. If it is a data pump file then you need `impdp` rather than `imp`. It might be useful to know the full export command used.

Comment: @AlexPoole
I've edited the question. `impdp` exists instantly as well. I've managet to take a quick snapshot, it is looking for an expdat.dmp. There is no such a file of course.

Comment: Please post text rather than images. We can't see how you're running it. It would be easier for us and for you if you open a command window and call `impdp.exe` explicitly from that, with appropriate arguments, particularly the file name (just the name not the full path). [See the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-D34AA2AC-DD27-4557-98AC-CE9A3AC21E35). If you do that with the `imp` version I suspect you'd see an error like 'IMP-00038' indicating the dump file isn't recognised (hopefully because it is a data pump file).

Comment: @AlexPoole
I've submitted the images, because `imp` and `impdp` windows shut down without any error messages instantly, so I can't even see them without taking a snapshot. To be honest I don't know the difference between `imp` and `impdp`. I've just got this dump file today to import it into our Oracle database and I'm trying to make sense out of it. I'm trying now with SQL Developer, but I'm also not sure whether the Data Pump function there is good for external .dmp files.

Comment: See the docs I already linked to for information about running `impdp`. [`exp` was desupported in 11g](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-original-export-utility.html#GUID-901CBBE0-65FB-439E-942D-F2038C18BCD2) and that and its sister `imp` should be very rarely used now. If you run `imp` or `impdp` from a command (aka DOS) window then you can supply arguments, that window won't disappear after an error, you'll be able to see what you're running and what happens, and you'll be able to copy text from that instead of having to try to capture an image.

Comment: @AlexPoole
Okay, thank you for the suggestions. I'm reviewing the docs at the moment.

Comment: You also really need to know, from your partner, how the data was exported and what the file contains so you can use the right import settings; and you need to run it as a suitable user and make sure you're in the right place - presumably a specific pluggable DB (called ZPD? from the default file path I guess that's OK, but the common user made me slightly twitchy...). Basically just be a bit careful, I suppose *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole
About the command line arguments: I can't give any arguments, because `impdp` stops right after login. 
The ZPD is the name of my database. I still don't know why it is searching for this `expdat.dmp` file without any further commands. Also this is just a local 18c database on my PC for now.

Comment: Because the way you're running it isn't supplying a non-default filename - that has to be given on the command line, not at an interactive prompt. It sounds like you're current double-clicking the `impdp.exe` file. As I already said, open a command window and run that from the command prompt instead, e.g. as `impdp dumpfile=planslab.dmp`, plus any other setting you need to provide.

Comment: @AlexPoole
Oh, I see. You are completely right, I was just running the .exe file. Okay, I'm gonna use the command with the proper .dmp file to check the messages.